# Multiple pie charts update with only one input d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts

I modified Mike Bostock's [Pie Chart Update III](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5681842) in order to get two different pie charts in one  using two  elements with one csv file for each chart.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var leftG = svg.append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 4 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var rightG = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + 3 * (width / 4) + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

I want to have each radio button updating **both** pie charts. Now my problem is that the update inputs only alter the second pie chart.

I can't figure out how to do this since the change() function is inside the d3.csv() function and one cannot access the other.

```
  d3.selectAll("input")
  .on("change", changeLeft);

  function changeLeft() {
    var value = this.value;
    pieLeft.value(function(d) { return d[value]; }); // change the value function
    pathLeft = pathLeft.data(pieLeft); // compute the new angles
    pathLeft.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween); // redraw the arcs
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :** Here is my [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tKgcej4h08yJzemvhgUl?p=preview)

Comment: please share you code through fiddle or jsbin

Comment: I added my code through plnkr

Answer (score 0):

declare a global variable

```
var changeLeft;
```

Replace your function with the below one and it will work:

```
 changeLeft = function() {
        var value = this.value;
        pieLeft.value(function(d) { return d[value]; }); // change the value function
        pathLeft = pathLeft.data(pieLeft); // compute the new angles
        pathLeft.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween); // redraw the arcs
      }
```

Comment: I tried this approach but it does not work (if I got it right), I get this 'pathLeft is not defined' error because the function is global and path is not recognized outside the d3.csv() function.

Comment: Well I tried on your plnkr it is working on top of wherever you get undefined for you need to increase the scope all concerned entities

Comment: I don't get it, where did you declare your function ? Would you mind updating the plnkr to show me please ?